# smallmatrix between brackets `[]` instead of parentheses `()`

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices, brackets, parentheses

I'm trying to write a math cheat sheet and have to write matrix in a compact way. I saw a very nice piece of answer [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261716/brackets-not-tall-enough-with-smallmatrix-from-amsmath). What I want to do know is to set the matrix in brackets `[]` instead of parentheses `()`. Any idea?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{psmallmatrix}
 {\hbox\bgroup
  \delimiterfactor=950
  \delimitershortfall=2pt
  $\left(\smallmatrix}
 {\endsmallmatrix\right)$\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    M =
    \begin{psmallmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{psmallmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Define a `bsmallmatrix` analogously just with `\left[` instead of `\left(` and `\right]` instead of `\right)`?

Comment: That was easy indeed. Didn't dig enough... Many thanks @moewe

Comment: Mathtools already provides this. All variants

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The  `mathtools` package extends `amsmath` for various features. In particular, it already defines the `psmallmatrix`, `bsmallmatrix`, `Bsmallmatrix`, `vsmallmatrix` , `Vsmallmatrix`  and their star variants which accept the columns alignment as an optional argument (default: `c`).